# Возможны ли атомарные операции без обертки std::atomic?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++11, атомарность

Возможны ли атомарные операции без обертки std::atomic? Мне нужна возможность работать с указателем и напрямую и атомарно, возможно ли применять cas к указателю который не обернут в std::atomic?

Comment: Да, помощью функций windows/linux

Comment: Или с использованием ассемблера.